# Eclipse - Java local history for file

Tags: java, eclipse, revision-history

Eclipse local history support a [file](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm)

> Every time an editable file is saved in the Workbench, the Workbench updates the local history of that file and logs the changes that have been made. The local history of a file can then be accessed and a previously saved copy of the file can be reverted to, as long as the desired state is recent enough in the save history.

But in [Java](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html) it seems to limit to Java type as method

> Whenever you edit a file, its previous contents are kept in the local history. Java tooling makes the local history available for Java elements, so you can revert back to a previous edition of a single method instead of the full file.

When try to get file history I get a popup error with *Please local history select a type, method or field*

How can I get history of my java file in eclipse? Is it enhancement or is there a workaround to see previous version of file

- Note for example if method signature changed I can't see previous method in history

Comment: Is there a reason to do this with pure eclipse? Why do you install git, create a local repository and then, use git from eclipse?

Comment: @CarlitosWay sometimes you can't commit your work, so I change file with working solution to other solution without updating TFS in my case

Comment: IMHO, you can do that using a branching schema in git, each branch is a possible solution, then, if you implement a solution that mets the requirements, that branch is merged into master...

Comment: @CarlitosWay it'll be alot easier to just see file history as regular file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full replace / compare options are available in the context menu in the Package Explorer and Project Explorer views.

Right click on the Java file and select 'Replace With > Local History....' or 'Compare With > Local History...'

Also note that you can control the amount of Local History that Eclipse keeps in the Preferences on the 'General > Workspace > Local History' page.